# Console Application to open a image in Windows 10 OS, Image opens but not able to go navigate to Next and Previous image in the sample folder

Tags: c#, process, console, photos

**My Environment:** Windows 10 Operating system in Desktop machine

**My purpose:** I have a "Sample_Pictures" folder in "My Documents" folder, this "Sample_Pictures" folder contains 5 pictures. I need to open an image (using C# console application) and then navigate to Next and Previous image in "Sample_Pictures" folder

**Issue I am facing:** I am able to open an image, but NOT able to navigate to Next and Previous pictures in folder. Both Next and Previous buttons are disabled. I mean the Next and Previous buttons present in image is NOT working in Windows 10 Photos. However If I open the same image separately in Windows Explorer, I am able to navigate to Next and Previous image.

**Sample Program:**

I found below code to open Photo App, however I am not able to open a specific image.
I am working on to find a complete solution.

```
private static void OpenSamplePhoto()
{
    string samplePicturesPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Sample_Pictures");

    string picturePath = Path.Combine(samplePicturesPath, "sample1.JPG");

    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = @"ms-photos://";
    info.Arguments = picturePath;
    info.UseShellExecute = true;
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    info.Verb = string.Empty;

    Process.Start(info);
}
```

I'm using [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/c624fb1f-e23a-4a53-88f4-393db07b2aa3/open-the-photo-with-microsoft-photos-windows-10-in-c-?forum=winforms) as a reference.

Comment: you need to have code that will get / Enumerate all files in a Directory using the `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` method, then you need a way to assign the images / getting next or previous, based on those files not selected in your current image list by it's name

Comment: According to your question your issue is with buttons, yet I see no code for buttons.  But Methodman is correct on the how to enumerate.

Comment: Okay, so you want to open that file with default image viewer and be able to move between them? I tested your code with custom location, with 2 images and I could do this, but opened image was twice - I had to click next button twice to show the second one.

Comment: I tested on W7, with default file browser, sample images in CommonPictures folder and it is just fine. Try to change info.workingDirectory to pictures folder.